# Unexpected PDF in `FirstPassageTimeDistribution`

Tags: probability-or-statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I am new to Markov Processes, and while learning the discrete Markov chain with the following matrix $$P=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$

I was told that $f_{34}(n)=\left(\frac14\right)^{n-1}\frac12$, where $f_{ij}(n)$ denotes the probability that starting in state $i$, we visit $j$ for the first time at time $n$. I can also verify this by hand.

I've tried the following input in Mathematica:

```
p = {{1/3, 2/3, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
P = DiscreteMarkovProcess[3, p];
f34 = FirstPassageTimeDistribution[P, 4];
PDF[f34, n]
```

But the result is $$\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 3 \times 4^{-n} & n>0 \\0 & \text { True }\end{array}\right.$$

I'm confused since $f_{34}(1)=p_{34}=\frac12$, how can it be $\frac34$ as given? I'm using the version 12.1.1.0, could anyone give me a hint where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try changing the third row of your stochastic matrix to say, `{13/20, 0, 1/4, 1/10}`. I'd venture you'd expect the probability to now be `1/10`, yes? But you'll see it's still `3/4`.  Now read the "Properties and Relations" section for the documentation of `FirstPassageTimeDistribution`, re: "When the target is one of the absorbing states, a conditional distribution is returned."

Comment: Hi ciao,could you please elaborate a bit. In the example from the help, there are 2 absorbing states,  state 1 and  target state. The condition is that the process does not get stuck in state 1. There are 2 problems here. In the example of Jeremy there is only the target absorbing state, no second one. What is the condition here? Second, If I eliminate  state 1 from the example from the help and calculate the transition prob. from the initial to the target state  PDF[f,2], I get 0.8 and not 0.89 as MMA claims.